npmでインストールしたパッケージをjestでモック化できない
jestでjavascriptのテストを作成しています。
テスト対象はtypescriptで記述し、コンパイルしてjavascriptファイルを出力しています。
remove.bgとsharpをモック化したいのですが、どうもうまく行きません。
何が間違っているのかわかる方はいませんか？
また、内容が重複する質問が既にあるならば、教えてくださいませんか？
ディレクトリ構造は以下の通りです。
src/  
|-handlers  
|    |- handler.ts  
|  
|-services  
|    |-removebgService.ts <- remove.bg  
|    |-sharpService.ts <- sharp  

環境
jest@29.7.0
remove.bg@1.3.0
sharp@0.33.5
typescript@5.6.3
npm 10.8.2
node v22.7.0
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "validators/*": ["validators/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}


いくつかのモック化の方法を試しました。
しかし、いずれもモックがされずエラーが発生するか本来のライブラリが実行されてしまいます。
jest.mock("remove.bg");
import * as removeBg from "remove.bg";

import * as removeBg from "remove.bg";
jest.mock("remove.bg");

jest.mock("remove.bg", () => {
  removeBackgroundFromImageUrl: jest.fn(),
});
import * as removeBg from "remove.bg";

import * as removeBg from "remove.bg";
jest.mock("remove.bg", () => {
  removeBackgroundFromImageUrl: jest.fn(),
});

jest.unstable_mockModule("remove.bg", () => {
  removeBackgroundFromImageUrl: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    base64img: readImg, // fs.readFileSync()で読み込んだサンプル画像
  }),
});
const {removeBackgroundFromImageUrl} = await import("remove.bg");

import * as removeBg from "remove.bg";
Object.assgin(removeBg, {
  removeBackgroundFromImageUrl:jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    base64img: readImg,
  })
});

import * as removeBg from "remove.bg";
Object.defineProperty(removeBg, "removeBackgroundFromImageUrl", {
  value: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    base64img: readImg,
  })
});

